# How to detect Hibernate in a Metro Application

Tags: microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, power-management

Is there any way to get notified in a metro application when a device goes into hibernate, to close an existing server connection?

Which could possible cause trouble when waking up again.

Answer (score 0):

There are events in Metro Style apps for Suspending and Resuming.

Note that these will not work while you are debugging in Visual Studio - Use the Suspend And Resume buttons on the debugging toolbar